# How can I reorder my indices pointing to vertices in a Blender Python export script so that my models will be connected correctly?

Tags: python, 3d, export, blender

I wrote a custom exporter that dumps a Blender mesh to a simple binary format. I can read extremely simple models like a cube from files exported by my script but more complex models like the monkey included with Blender do not work. Instead, complex models have many of the vertices connected wrongly. I believe that when I am looping through the vertex indices in my script I am not doing so in the right order. How can I reorder indices pointing to vertices in a Blender Python export script so that my vertices will be connected correctly? Below is the exporter script (with comments that explain the file format.)

```
import struct
import bpy

def to_index(number):
    return struct.pack(">I", number)

def to_GLfloat(number):
    return struct.pack(">f", number)

# Output file structure
# A file is a single mesh
#
# A mesh is a list of vertices, normals, and indices
#
# index number_of_triangles
# triangle triangles[number_of_triangles]
# index number_of_vertices
# vertex vertices[number_of_vertices]
# normal vertices[number_of_vertices]
#
# A triangles is a 3-tuple of indices pointing to vertices in the corresponding vertex list
#
# index vertices[3]
#
# A vertex is a 3-tuple of GLfloats
#
# GLfloat coordinates[3]
#
# A normal is a 3-tuple of GLfloats
#
# GLfloat normal[3]
#
# A GLfloat is a big endian 4 byte floating point IEEE 754 binary number
# An index is a big endian unsigned 4 byte binary number

def write_kmb_file(context, filepath):

    meshes = bpy.data.meshes

    if 1 != len(meshes):
        raise Exception("Expected a single mesh")

    mesh = meshes[0]

    faces = mesh.polygons
    vertex_list = mesh.vertices

    output = to_index(len(faces))

    for face in faces:
        vertices = face.vertices
        if len(vertices) != 3:
            raise Exception("Only triangles were expected")

        output += to_index(vertices[0])
        output += to_index(vertices[1])
        output += to_index(vertices[2])

    output += to_index(len(vertex_list))

    for vertex in vertex_list:
        x, y, z = vertex.co.to_tuple()
        output += to_GLfloat(x)
        output += to_GLfloat(y)
        output += to_GLfloat(z)

    for vertex in vertex_list:
        x, y, z, = vertex.normal.to_tuple()
        output += to_GLfloat(x)
        output += to_GLfloat(y)
        output += to_GLfloat(z)


    out = open(filepath, 'wb')
    out.write(output)
    out.close()

    return {'FINISHED'}


from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty
from bpy.types import Operator


class ExportKludgyMess(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "mesh.export_to_kmb"
    bl_label = "Export KMB"

    filename_ext = ".kmb"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.kmb",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        return write_kmb_file(context, self.filepath)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportKludgyMess)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your most likely just dumping the verts. Since each vert is used in multiple faces file formats like obj indicates verts with 'v', vert normals with 'vn' and UVs with 'vt'. However this is NOT the draw order. The 'f' prefix indicates with order of verts for each face. For

example f 1/1/1 2/4/3 3/4/5 use
verts 1,2,3
normals 1,4,4
UV 1,3,5

I know its old but hey.